# MySQL Unique and Index

Tags: mysql, indexing

If I have a UNIQUE across 2 columns do I still need to add an INDEX for each column?

Or does the UNIQUE also INDEX both columns?

Note: data will be required for many queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you declare a `unique` contraint on a column(s), it automatically adds an index for it.

Answer (score 2):

`UNIQUE` is an index ***and*** a constraint.