# How to index usernames in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I know this is a basic question, I've search around and haven't been able to find a simple enough answer for what I'm doing.

I want to improve upon this query

```
select * from users where username = 'myusername';
```

Currently there are about 4000+ plus users and I want to add indexing to the username so that if the username begins with 'r', it only looks to all the usernames that begin with 'r' vs all users. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider adding `UNIQUE` constraint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211475/mysql-unique-and-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index with something along the lines of

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON users (username);
```

where `index_name` is the name of the index you want to create. Be aware that indexing will slow down inserts and updates, so don't index something that needs to be updated very fast.

Comment: ok but how do I use the 'indexing' how do ask it only search for usernames that begin with 'r'

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "r%";`

Comment: would something like this be efficient:  select * from users where username like '$r' and username = 'robert' limit 1 or is there a better way to loop through all the 'r' usernames?